# Trying to print a multi-grid WPF that contains WPF charting toolkit charts but getting a stack overflow exception

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, charts

I currently have an application that contains several different grids, each representing a different page that needs to be printed.  I was able to build a fixed document and print out everything until I needed to add a chart to one of the grids. Now on two of these Grids it collects user data that is then plotted into a chart using the WPF charting toolkit.  When I try to clone the grids that contain the charts and try to add them to the the Fix Document I get a stack overflow execption which is triggered by the line of code 
String gridXaml = XamlWriter.Save(GridName);

```
    private void Print_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        pd.UserPageRangeEnabled = true;

        document = new FixedDocument();

        AddPage(MPEval);
        AddPage(QC);
        AddPage(ID);
        AddPage(AWS);
        AddPage(GAR);
        AddPage(SA);
        AddPage(UAG);
        AddPage(LCD);
        AddPage(RFVolume);
        AddPage(RFSurface);

        if (pd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {

            DocumentPaginator paginator = document.DocumentPaginator;

            if (pd.PageRangeSelection == PageRangeSelection.UserPages)
            {
                paginator = new PageRangeDocumentPaginator(document.DocumentPaginator, pd.PageRange);
            }
            pd.PrintDocument(paginator, MPSite.Text);

        }
    }

    private void AddPage(Grid gridName)
    {
        var pageSize = new Size(8.26 * 96, 11.69 * 96); // A4 page, at 96 dpi
        document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = pageSize;
        // Create FixedPage
        var fixedPage = new FixedPage();
        fixedPage.Width = pageSize.Width;
        fixedPage.Height = pageSize.Height;
        // Add visual, measure/arrange page.
        String gridXaml = XamlWriter.Save(gridName);
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(gridXaml);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlTextReader.Create(stringReader, new XmlReaderSettings());
        Grid tempGrid = (Grid)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
        fixedPage.Children.Add((UIElement)tempGrid);
        fixedPage.Measure(pageSize);
        fixedPage.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(), pageSize));
        fixedPage.UpdateLayout();

        // Add page to document
        var pageContent = new PageContent();
        ((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
        document.Pages.Add(pageContent);
    }
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction on how to be able to add these to my fixed document or let me know if I have hit a dead end and need to go another route.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look and see if this will work for you:

```
 System.Xaml.XamlServices.Save(GridName);
```

The problem you are experiencing is due to a recursive call.

Comment: That changed the exception to a "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xaml.XamlObjectReaderException' occurred in System.Xaml.dll"  I will have to look into this exception and see if I can work around this one.  Thank you for your fast response.